# Language recommendations for an efficient web crawler

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node.js, web-crawler

I'm looking for a language for writing an efficient web crawler.  Things I value:

- expressive language (don't make me just through static typing hoops)
- useful libraries (a css selector based html parser would be nice)
- minimal memory footprint
- dependable language runtime & libraries

I tried node.js.  I like node in theory.  Javascript is very expressive.  You can use jQuery to parse html.  Node's async nature lets me crawl many urls in parallel without dealing with threads.  V8 is nice and fast for parsing.

In practice, node isn't working out for me.  My process constantly crashes.  Bus Errors, exceptions in the event manager ... etc.

I've done a fair bit of Ruby dev, so I wouldn't mind using Ruby 1.9's coroutines (fibers?) as long as I won't face similar issues with VM / library stability.

Additional suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Use Node.js, and fix whatever is crashing it. It's been running on my Ubuntu box without any problems for months.

For the library, I recommend to use YUI3 instead of jQuery, it easily lets you build a webcrawler/scraper in a couple of minutes, if you don't believe me watch [this Talk](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/01/video-yuiconf2010-glass/) from YUIConf2010, it's 40 minutes but it's all about code.

Dav Glass did a great job of showing how easy it is and how little code you need, yes there were some issues with different version of jsdom in the talk, but the talk was given at the beginning of November, so much of that should have been fixed already.

You can check out all the stuff from the talk at his [GitHub page](https://github.com/davglass).
And here's his [scraper](https://github.com/davglass/nodejs-yui3/blob/master/examples/scrape.js) that gets the current news headlines from Digg.

Seriously it's more than worth the effort making Node.js run on your system, since in the end you got all the awesomeness of YUI3 on the server side.

Comment: I just found another issue.  jsdom's jQuerify method isn't executing the callback about 80% of the time.  It seems that the onload callback of the added script element isn't executed.  It seems strange that I should have to simulate a browser environment complete with script loading to perform html scraping.

Comment: I agree.  The only way to know if you have the right hammer for the job is if you know exactly why the one you have isn't working.  Fix this first.

Comment: @richcollins There's no need to load the scripts, in fact as of now, no framework out there does execute the JS of the page. All it does for now is to provide the exact same API as YUI3 inside the browser. Which in terms of interoperability is just top notch. Also, I don't think that this will be performance problem in any way. I've used for example Beautiful soup in the past and to be honest, I can't imagine anything that's slower than that :/

Comment: It looks like YUI can be installed as an npm module.  The jsdom + jQuery approach actually adds a script tag to the document, loads it and then performs a callback to tell you that it loaded.  I'd rather use jQuery because I'm (and follow on devs) familiar with its API, but I'm happy to use YUI if it causes fewer problems.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: YUI + jsdom is leaking memory like crazy :-(

Comment: @richcollins That's bad :/ Guess they still have a lot of work to do with jsdom then, or you are doing something wrong (like keeping references around) but I can't imagine that. The DOM approach is still the easiest, beautiful soup for Python is another solution but soup is really slow because it tries to make sense out the biggest mess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure any language has something built that can handle it. Are you sure node.js isn't crashing because of a problem in your code? Why not use Ruby if you're comfortable with it?

There's also [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Python), which you might consider if you main hurdle is the HTML parsing.

Comment: I'm sure that the crashes aren't caused by problems in my code.  It's more likely that my code is exposing problems in node.  Especially in the case of the Bus Error.  I like Ruby, I just don't have any experience writing async code in Ruby, so I don't know if it is as "easy" as it is in node.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the language most familiar to you or the language you want to learn most. You can write a web crawler in any language.

I've personally developed crawlers in Java, Ruby, and Perl. All of these languages met your requirements. (Yes, even the crawler in Java had a reasonable memory footprint.) Of these, Java was my favorite because it boasted the most mature HTTP and HTML libraries. If I find myself writing another, I want to try Python next.

The first algorithmic problem you'll face is the task of efficiently identifying the pages you've already visited. This index of URLs can grow very large and must support fast lookups and insertions. A common database index will work in early crawler prototypes but will quickly prove to be the bottleneck.

Comment: I'm just going to use my db (tokyocabinet) to keep track of crawl state.  I can augment with memcache if needed, but memcache shouldn't be required as long as I can fit the TC db in memory.

Answer (score 0):

python and BeautifulSoup, easy to learn and very efficient.